# Multiple Routes in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have been trying to make this work and I have done many research but I can't find the answer. I am creating a application with multiple routes outlet in angular 2+.

I have this:

App.Component.html

```
<div>
<div>
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
  <a mat-tab-link
     *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
     [routerLink]="{ outlets: {form: link.path } }"
     routerLinkActive="active-link" #rla="routerLinkActive"
     [active]="rla.isActive">
    <span><mat-icon>{{link.icon}}</mat-icon></span>
    <span>{{link.label}}</span>
  </a>
</nav>
    <router-outlet name="form"></router-outlet>
</div>
</div>




 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      { path: "hotel",  component: HotelSearchFormApiComponent, outlet:"form"},
      { path: "groups", component: GroupRequestFormComponent, outlet:"form"},
      { path: "flight", component: flightsSearchFormComponent, outlet:"form"},
      { path: "", component: HomeComponent},
      //{ path: "", redirectTo: "hotel", pathMatch: "full" },
      { path: "**", redirectTo: "hotel" },
    ]
   },
  { path: 'hotel/rate',      component:  RatesComponent },
  { path: 'hotel/:countryCod/:stateCod/:cityCod/:dateFrom/:dateTo',      component:  SearchHotelResultComponent },
```

App.component.ts

```
navLinks = [
{
    path:'./home/hotel',
    icon: 'hotel',
    label:   'Hoteles'
},
{
    path:'/home/flight',
    icon:'flight',
    label: 'Vuelos'
}
,
{
    path:'./home/Package',
    icon:'work',
    label: 'Paquetes'
}
,
{
    path:'./home/groups',
    icon:'group',
    label: 'Grupos'
}
]
```

But when I click on the button I got this issue:

```
error: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '/home/flight' at ApplyRedirects.push.../../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (http://localhost/a/vendor.js:140670:16) at CatchSubscriber.selector (http://localhost/a/vendor.js:140651:29) at CatchSubscriber.push.../../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (http://localhost/a/vendor.js:181982:31) at MapSubscriber.push.../../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (http://localhost/a/vendor.js:178721:26) at MapSubscriber.push.../../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (http://localhost/a/vendor.js:178701:18) at MapSubscriber.push.../../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (http://localhost/a/vendor.js:178721:26) at MapSubscriber.push.../../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (http://localhost/a/vendor.js:178701:18) at MapSubscriber.push.../../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (http://localhost/a/vendor.js:178721:26) at MapSubscriber.push.../../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (http://localhost/a/vendor.js:178701:18) at TapSubscriber.push.../../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error (http://localhost/a/vendor.js:186715:26)
message: "Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '/home/flight'"
stack: "Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '/home/flight'↵    at ApplyRedirects.push.../../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (http://localhost/a/vendor.js:140670:16)↵    at CatchSubscriber.selector (http://localhost/a/vendor.js:140651:29)↵    at CatchSubscriber.push.../../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (http://localhost/a/vendor.js:181982:31)↵    at MapSubscriber.push.../../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (http://localhost/a/vendor.js:178721:26)↵    at MapSubscriber.push.../../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (http://localhost/a/vendor.js:178701:18)↵    at MapSubscriber.push.../../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (http://localhost/a/vendor.js:178721:26)↵    at MapSubscriber.push.../../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (http://localhost/a/vendor.js:178701:18)↵    at MapSubscriber.push.../../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (http://localhost/a/vendor.js:178721:26)↵    at MapSubscriber.push.../../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (http://localhost/a/vendor.js:178701:18)↵    at TapSubscriber.push.../../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error (http://localhost/a/vendor.js:186715:26)"
__proto__: Object
id: 3
url: "/home(form:/home/flight)"
```

Also, /Home is not redirecting to home/hotel.

I used to have a single outlet and was working flawless :(.

Thanks in advance.

Andrés

Comment: Did you add <router-outlet></router-outlet> in HomeComponent?

Comment: Yes sir. I have made it work now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you have here is that you're trying to navigate to a route that doesn't exist. Let me explain a bit more here, you have a route called home lets say this looks something like:

```
export const HomeRoutes:Routes=[
{path:'home', component:HomeComponent}
];
```

This will bring you to you home page.

now in your home page you want to have a new `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` that will allow you to have children of `/home`. You will need to add the children to the route. It may looks something like:

```
export const HomeRoutes:Routes=[
{path:'home', component:HomeComponent, children:[
    {path:'groups', component:GroupsComponent}
]}
];
```

So now if you go to `/home/groups` you will actually be navigation to 2 components your `HomeComponent` and `GroupsComponent` that is inside the home component.

any you can have as many of those as you desire.

Hope this explains a bit better.

The full documentation is [Here](https://angular.io/api/router/Routes)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you **didn't initialized** variable `appRoutes`. You need to add it into the import block of the App module.

```
     import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
     @NgModule({
        ...
            imports: [
                ...
                RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
            ],
        ...
        })
       export class AppModule{}
```